# read & write from file

Tags: c++, file

I want to write a program in c++ that prompts a user for a file name of an existing file that contains 10 records where the length of each record is 12 characters. next the program seeks to the beginning of the 6th record, reads the records in the file and append them to the end of an existing output file that contains 3 records.
Thank you.

Comment: Is there a question?  That is just a statement of what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like a cool idea!

Comment: Is this for an homework?

Comment: Ok. Where are you having trouble? Any [good introductory C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c++-book-guide-and-list) will cover how to perform basic I/O like this.

Comment: Please change "I want to" to "My professor wants me to". Nobody on SO will do the work for you or give you help if you didn't even cope with the problem yourself. Show us what you have already.

Answer (score 6):

You may find this useful:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "McDonaldsApplication.h" 

int main()
{
  McDonaldsApplication app;
  string name, dob, pos, ssn;
  std::cout << "Enter your name: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> name;
  std::cout << "Enter your DOB: " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> dob;
  std::cout << "Enter your SSN: "  << std::endl;
  std::cin >> ssn;
  std::cout << "Enter your desired position (0,1,2): " << std::endl;
  std::cin >> pos;
  std::cout << "Thank you! Your application is being submitted now\n";
  app.setName(name);
  app.setDob(dob);
  app.setSsn(ssn);
  app.setPos(pos);
  app.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't actually ask a question (questions end in a '?') I'll post a semi-related implementation of what you may have meant, in a language of my choice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace TestConsole
{
 class Program
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/careers.html
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="args"></param>
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("c:\\mcdonalds_app.txt"))
   {
    writer.WriteLine("Hello, my name is {0}. I'd love to work here!", args[0]);
    writer.Close();
   }
  }
 }
}
```